# Step by step conversion from recursive function to closed-form

Tags: closed-form, recursion

Currently, I'm interested about Pascal's triangle and binomial coefficients. To train my skills in programming, I plotted a Pascal triangle using only its image. So, I got a beautiful recursive function that looks like as:
$$  p(l,r) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $l$ or $r$ is 0} \\
p(l-1,r)+p(l,r-1), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$l$ and $r$ means are positions number on left side and right side. However, we can transform this function for $n$ and $k$ arguments("$n$ choose $k$") and got:
$$  p(n,k) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $k$ is 0} \\
1,  & \text{if $n=k$} \\
p(n-1,k)+p(n-1,k-1), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
However, there a closed function exists for equivalent computing: 
$$b(n,k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

**Question:**

1)I'm interested in a step-by-step transformation for $p(n,k)$ from recursive-form to a closed analog with a detailed explanation.

*My short comment*: It may be difficult, since this function is not primitive recursive function, but is there a general algorithm exists?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is a "general theory" of *hypergeometric functions*, and an algorithm ([Zeilberger's algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html)) which allows one to find closed forms of recurrences as stated in the question. This is not my area of expertise, I simply happen to know about this. [There is a book $A = B$ available for free](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf) written by Zeilberger himself which explains this algorithm.